# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. When uploading an Image this error occure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, file-upload, runtime-error

##Here is the LoginController##

> When submit the save button , it shows the Object refference not set to an instance of an object at the following code.

```
namespace VeriSettle.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        DTable dl = new DTable();
        //Add Property using Store Procedure
        public ActionResult Property()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Property(Property p, HttpPostedFileBase image)
        {
            string filepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/PropertyImage"), image.FileName);
            image.SaveAs(filepath);
            dl.insertProperty(p);
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Data  Saved')</script>");
            return View(p);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: It shows error at this line
""" string filepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/PropertyImage"), image.FileName); """

Comment: You haven't told us what programming language  this is!

Comment: c# language @greg-449